# Open a new tab with href in HTML

Tags: html, hyperlink, href

First, let me get one thing clear: I need to *open a new tab*, not to *open a link in a new tab*. I've tried (HTML)

```html
<a href="about:newtab">Link</a>
```

```html
<a href="about:home">Link</a>
```

but it just stays on the same page. The only thing that seems to work is

```html
<a href="about:blank">Link</a>
```

but it's just a flat white screen, and I'd very much prefer a normal new tab. I've searched the web throughly but the only thing I can find is how to open a link in a new tab (`target="_blank"`). So if anyone knows how to do this, please tell me. I am using Firefox, if it makes a difference.

Comment: open a new tab with what on it? why doesn't `target="_blank"` work?

Comment: What is a "normal new tab"? You mean with whatever the browser shows, like Chrome shows google and Edge shows Binck or so?

Comment: I'ts not really nice, just a flat white screen. A new tab is much better, as it has the user's preferences, links, bookmarks, etc. Do you like `about:blank` better as your homepage?

Comment: You cannot do that with a javascript in a page, Selenium can: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42670160/selenium-webdriver-trying-to-use-ctrl-t-to-open-a-tab-javascript

Comment: @mplungjan yes, with the search bar and stuff